# Adding Comment Replies to Posts as an Array of Strings in Class "Post"

Tags: ios, swift

I have created an app where users can generate posts that are added to a postTableView. Users can then click on any of the cells of postTableView to go to a unique view with the title and text of the post along with a commentTableView filled with user generated comments. Below the commentTableView is a textView that you can write your comment in and a button allowing you to submit your comment. I am trying to code my app so that when you press the button, the text that you wrote in the textView is appended to an array of unique comments for that post. Those comments populate the commentTableView. The following is my current flawed attempt:

Here is the Post Class:

```
import Foundation

class Post {
var id:String
var title: String
var text:String
var createdAt:Date
var comment: [String] = []

init(id: String, title: String,text:String,  timestamp:Double, comment: [String] = []) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)




}
static func parse(_ key:String, data:[String:Any]) -> Post? {
    if let title = data["text"] as? String,
        let text = data["title"] as? String,
        let timestamp = data["timestamp"] as? Double {
        return Post(id: key, title: title,  text: text, timestamp:timestamp, comment: [])
        }

    return nil
    }
}
```

Here is my current view controller that you get when you click on any of the cells from the postTableView:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainTextView: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var commentPlaceHolder: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var newCommentLabel: UITextView!
var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?
@IBAction func postReplyButton() {


    // Firebase code here
    let postRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts").childByAutoId()

    let postObject = [
        "comment": newCommentLabel.text,
        "timestamp": [".sv": "timestamp"]
        ] as [String : Any]

    postRef.setValue(postObject, withCompletionBlock: { error, ref in
        if error == nil {
            self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID: ref.key!)
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }  else {
            // Handle error

        }
    })
    newCommentLabel.text = String()
    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = false
}
var post: Post?

// MARK: - View Controller LifeCycle

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.setMain()

}
```

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
newCommentLabel.delegate = self as! UITextViewDelegate
```

}

```
private func setMain() {
    guard let post = self.post else {
        return
    }

    titleText.text = post.text
    mainText.text = post.title
}
func textViewDidChange(_commentView: UITextView) {

    commentPlaceHolder.isHidden = !newCommentLabel.text.isEmpty

}
```

}

How can I fix my errors and programmatically execute my vision of populating my comment section with user for each post?

Answer (score 0):

For

> Class 'MainTextView' has no initializers

Replace

```
var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate
```

with

```
var delegate:NewPostVCDelegate?
```

Comment: I get the error: "'weak' must not be applied to non-class-bound 'NewPostVCDelegate'; consider adding a protocol conformance that has a class bound". When I remove weak and add an optional for self.delegate!.didUploadPost(withID:ref.key!) the program crashes when I tap a cell in my postViewController.

Comment: how you present `MainTextView`

Comment: segue / present / push ?

Comment: I get the following error when I click a cell: " 2019-06-13 19:19:16.687240+0200 FirebaseApp[70208:6990630] Could not cast value of type 'FirebaseApp.MainTextView' (0x1021b2ba0) to 'UITextViewDelegate' (0x108cd14f8)."

Comment: `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
        
        if let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainTextView") as? MainTextView {
            destination.post = (posts[indexPath.row])
            navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
        }
    
    }
   
} `

Comment: I edited the original post with the new MainTextView code